# Receiving Package xkeyval Error: `x' undefined in families `blx@opt@name'

Tags: bibliographies, xkeyval

I am using TeX-Live on a Mac with macOS 11.6.1 with the latest TeX Live version. All packages are updated today.

When I am building my LaTeX document with `\printbibliography` I receive the following error:

> Package xkeyval Error: `x' undefined in families `blx@opt@name'.

Building without `\printbibliography` is error free. I also cleared all .aux files before trying it a couple of times which didn't solve the problem.

I am lost, what can I do?

Comment: you will have to show a small but complete example which demonstrates the error.

Comment: An issue like this is almost impossible to debug without a short example document that reproduces the error. Please follow the instructions in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 (and linked pages) to create a document that we can use to investigate the problem.

Comment: I voted to close this question, because it cannot be reasonably investigated without a short example document that reproduces the error. I will happily vote to reopen once more details (ideally an example document) are added (just ping me).